# Solaris + run my script after Solaris boot/reboot

Tags: linux, solaris, boot

I have a Solaris machine ( Solaris installed on   Netra-T2000 HW , Solaris version – 5.10 )

I wrote the script called update_after_solaris_already_boot.ksh

This script should automatically  update some files/configuration after Solaris completely  has finished the boot process.

My question: Where do I need to put  script in order to run my it only after Solaris is completely booted?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want/need to manage your script using services (svcs) then you could put your script in `/etc/rc3.d` e.g. `/etc/rc3.d/S99update_after_solaris_already_boot.ksh`. The files here are run in lexicographical order and must start with an `S` to started at run level 3. Have a read of the `/etc/init.d/README` and `/etc/rc3.d/README` files for more information.